# scientific notation with small numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, scientific-notation

I need to work with numbers written in scientific notation. I know that currently JS uses scientific notation only for big and small numbers.

Example:

`1000000000000000000000 === 1e+21`

`0.0000001 === 1e-7`

I would like to have the same notation with every number.

Example:

`10` should be `1e+1`

I have already tried to use the method `.toExponential`, but the number is converted to a `string`.

I need to keep the `number` type.

Any suggestion?

Comment: A number is a number is a number; the internal representation is consistent regardless of the value.

Comment: You *cannot* have a formatted value that's a number. `100` is going to be the same value as `1e2` as they have a single representation. There is no display information attached to numeric values. The engine will just show large numbers as exponents but that's entirely visual - that's *not* the numeric value held in memory. It's always a 64-bit IEEE 754 float representation. If you need to have a value in a specific format, you need to use a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number` to convert the scientific notation string back to a number. `.toExponential` will return a string in the spec, so that's what you get.

```js
console.log( Number('1e+4') );
console.log( Number('1e-4') );
console.log( typeof Number('1e-4') );
```

Comment: For `1e-7` and smaller it is still shown with scientitic notation.

Comment: @Shikkou That is true when you `console.log` the number. That's just default behavior of a Number type. You can use `.toExponential()` if you don't want that. However with my suggestion you can consistently write scientific notation in your codebase and convert strings in scientific notation or normal numbers from storage to have the same number-type in your codebase.